# How to fill empty string with %20 from an array of strings ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string

I have a String array which I found from JSON object. It's an Image array containing 4 images presently.I don't know how many images I will get in future.
My Question is the Image URL is not showing in my ImageView Because it contains some blank space with it.I have already checked if this space is replaced with %20 then I can happily use it in my ImageView.

Can Anyone Suggest me how can I replace all the blank space from all the image String URL which is there in this Image Array?

Please Found my Code for the same:-----

```
    NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"BANNER"];

    NSMutableArray *data=[NSMutableArray new];

      if (!latest) {

        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@",error);
    }
       else{

        for(int i=0; i<latest.count ; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [latest objectAtIndex:i];

            [data addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"url"]];
        }
        NSLog(@"data :%@",data);
        }
```

# Pragma Mark: I have Found image array in the below format

```
data :(
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508139616-Food Offer Banner App (1).jpg",
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508163055-Serving  Banner app.jpg",
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508746128-Food App Banner Deal10.jpg",
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508746172-Food Banner Features.jpg"
)
```

## Pragma Mark: I want to convert "data" like this

```
data :(
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508139616-Food%20Offer%20Banner%20App%20(1).jpg",
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508163055-Serving%20Banne%20app.jpg",
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508746128-Food%20App%20Banner%20Deal10.jpg",
    "https://xyz.in/mobile/1508746172-Food%20Banner%20Features.jpg"
)
```

I know this Question is already there but for single string only.But My Question is I want to convert the complete Array of String Url.
Please Help me Already Spent 3-4 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`. It can help you replace all space with `%20`.

```
yourImageUrlString = [yourImageUrlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

For your code

```
NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"BANNER"];

NSMutableArray *data=[NSMutableArray new];

if (!latest) {

  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@",error);
}
else{

  for(int i=0; i<latest.count ; i++)
  {
    NSDictionary *dict = [latest objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];
    url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    [data addObject:url];
  }
  NSLog(@"data :%@",data);
}
```

Comment: Thank You So much.Awesome Answer solved within a minute @trungduc

Comment: @srsstyle Welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't just replace empty space with `%20` there are other special characters that could cause issues with url. You must be using percent encoding. Something like this.

```
NSString *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: I will try this @Bilal

Comment: Also Solved my Problem bro @Bilal